# Change background when pushing inside UI navigation Controller

Tags: ios, arrays, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UInaviguationController in my App. My question is how to make the backgroundView when pushing a viewController the view of the current scene. The default is black screen. I would like to achieve something similar to presenting Modally over the current Context inside a UINaviguationController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you are going from View Controller A to View Controller B.

You could try something like taking a screenshot of the background view of A right before you push B using Navigation Controller.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[targetView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then pass this image to view controller B and set it up as the background image. If you also want the same animation as presenting a view controller modally, you will have to use custom navigation controller animation and set it up.

Edit: If all you wanted to do is show the same solid color on B as that of A. Just set the background color of B to that of A and add a custom navigation controller animation

For the animation,
You will have to set the View Controller to be a delegate of the navigationController. Then you will have to add the following delegate function:

```
-(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
        {
        return [[Slide alloc] init];
    }
```

Then return the class you will create to implement the animation. You will have to make the class you make conform to the `<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>` protocol

The class will have to implement the following two delegate functions-

```
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
        return 0.4f;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
UIViewController* toController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
UIViewController* fromController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIView* container = [transitionContext containerView];
[container addSubview:toController.view];

 [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        //set frame to be out of screen bounds here
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [fromController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [transitionContext completeTransition:finished];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you provide a swift version for you answer ? Also how to pass the image taken ?

Comment: Setup a strong UIImage property in the header file in objective C. When you are writing the code for pushing view controller B you jsut have to write

ViewControllerB.image = yourImage;

Sorry i'm not all that familiar with swift and will probably end up misdirecting you. I have already told you how to do it objective C, you should be able to get an idea and do it in swift.